# How to find the image location [Docker]

Tags: docker, backend

I've started learning Docker recently and when doing an exercise about image manipulation, using the cowsay image, the solution to create an ENTRYPOINT was:

```
        ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/games/cowsay" ]
```

I understand why to use this file to run the program but how do I know where the image is to refer to?

Comment: Do you have a more complete Dockerfile?  What was the problem you were running into previously?  The images themselves are stored in an opaque format in private Docker space and you can't directly access them (though in many cases you can launch `ls` or an interactive shell instead of the main container process; easier if you specify `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT`).

Comment: I recommend reading the [`Dockerfile` reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

Comment: Thanks for helping! I had to create an ENTRYPOINT to execute the command and then use CMD to define a default message from the image. The Dockerfile should be that simple and then to build an image in a container to run the program. I mean, where to find the image file path in my machine? It was stored in /usr/games/, how to know this previously?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.